# Why does MySQL safe update mode not allow a LIKE predicate?

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following scenario:

- I have a MySQL table called `actor`. (Yes, it's from the Sakila sample DB).
- In the table there's a varchar column called `last_name`.
- There is a (non-PRIMARY) KEY on the column.
- MySQL safe update mode is turned on.

When I run this query, it works:

```
DELETE FROM actor WHERE last_name = 'foo';
```

When I run this query:

```
DELETE FROM actor WHERE last_name LIKE '%fo' OR last_name LIKE 'fo%';
```

It fails with this error message:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

**Why does safe update mode stop the second command and allow the first command?**

Comment: `=` is very specific, it's unlikely to delete a row you didn't intend. `LIKE` can easily match more than you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Is this documented anywhere? IMHO you can do a lot of damage with the `=` predicate. Just consider the last name 'Smith' :)

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) but it doesn't mention this detail. I'm just extrapolating.

Comment: The general idea of safe updates is to block queries that might affect many more rows than you expected.

Comment: @Barmar. I now see the page you linked to provides a (somewhat vague) answer to my question. See *"...if the optimizer decides not to use the index on the key column:"*. Would you like to post an answer with these details? I'll accept it.

Comment: `LIKE 'fo%'` should use an index, so I don't think that's the explanation. If it were `LIKE '%fo'` it would explain it.

Comment: Why are you using backtick in second example instead of `'`.  `DELETE FROM actor WHERE last_name LIKE 'fo%';`?

Comment: @lukasz-szozda Tx. Typo. Fixing now.

Comment: I can't reproduced the error. I get the error with `LIKE '%a'` but not with `LIKE 'a%'`.

Comment: Which type of pattern did you actually use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates):

> It is possible for UPDATE and DELETE statements to produce an error in safe-updates mode even with a key specified in the WHERE clause, if the optimizer decides not to use the index on the key column.

A test like `LIKE 'fo%'` will normally use the index (the index can be used to match the beginning of a column), so it shouldn't cause the error. But a test like `LIKE '%fo'` cannot be indexed (it doesn't specify the beginning of the column, so a full scan is necessary), so you get an error.

Comment: thanks. You are right. `LIKE 'fo%'` should work. In my case it fails because of a foreign key constraint. One of the records to be deleted has a corresponding record in another table. Changing my question to use `LIKE '%fo'` because that was what gave me the 1175 error to begin with.

Comment: So you didn't really get the error about safe update mode?

Comment: I did, only what I used in the workbench was `WHERE first_name LIKE '%fo' OR first_name LIKE 'fo%';`. Sorry - I should have been more accurate in my description of the problem.